# Setting log level for java.lang.System.Logger on cmdline

Tags: java, openjdk-17

Is there a way to set the logging level for the `java.lang.System.Logger` on the command line? Using properties files baked into the JAR is a no-go, since I want to have the same JAR in staging and production environments with the difference that the staging environment has more verbose logging.

Answer (score 0):

Each implementation of `java.lang.System.Logger` works differently, so there's no uniform way to set it for all implementations.

If you happen to use `SimpleConsoleLogger`, you can set the environment variable `jdk.system.logger.level`.

Comment: Right, I hadn't configured the logger myself for this software. It's using java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler